# Is It Secure To Send Emails From Desktop Application?

Tags: .net, security, email, desktop-application, email-client

I'm going to use email service (gmail or yahoo etc) in my .net desktop application.
I'll use email service to send Error reports, Submit contact forms and Purchasing request (with user permission)

I'll not store my login information in my application source. Login information (i.e Username and Password) will be scraped from web in encrypted form. Then my software will descry it after scraping.

- No one can get login information from source code. (Because It was not there, It will be scraped from web)
- No one can get login info from web. (Because It's hidden path and also in my own encrypted form)

But I'm still afraid is it secure to use Email Service in desktop programs because Some antiviruses like "Avast" monitor SMPT port and add there logo and captions in our each outgoing emails. So our email can be read without login info. If Avast can edit our emails may be it can also get our password.

Comment: I could get the login information from your app by (among other things) taking a memory dump at the appropriate time. The only way to be fully secure with authentication credentials is to use the SecureString type. Unfortunately, that type is not well-supported by other services.

Comment: So what should I do to send information (error reports and feedback etc) from my desktop application to me? If email is not fully secure and can be hijack from "Memory Dump" method.
Also what you mean by "SecureString"?

Comment: SecureString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Comment: For error reporting, you might consider hosting a web service instead of e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No one can get login info from web. (Because It's hidden path and also in my own encrypted form)

A hidden path is not a good place to store secure information. This is akin to storing your house key under the plantpot. Since the user has control of the client machine they would also be likely to be able to retrieve this by a memory dump or by some other means.

### What you should do

Rather than send the mail directly from your desktop app, you should create and host a web service on your server. The desktop app will make a web service request to your web service, and the web service will handle the sending of the email. This way your email credentials and your from/to address will be controlled securely from your web service, outside the control of the desktop application, its users and any anti virus software.

You should also use [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29990/8340) to access your service over HTTPS to ensure your app is only communicating with the trusted web service and ensure that any credentials used for your web service remain secure. You could have a private key per installation in order to authenticate each desktop app with your web service. In the event of any breach you simply revoke that key server side rather than it putting your whole email system at risk.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm still afraid is it secure to use Email Service in desktop programs because Some antiviruses like "Avast" monitor SMPT port and add there logo and captions in our each outgoing emails.

Use an encrypted connection for the SMTP transmission (such as SMTP with SSL).  This should prevent the anti virus software from being able to intercept and decipher the data.

Most modern email hosting services allow SMTP connections with SSL.

Comment: Gmail is SSL but still avast can modify our outgoing emails.

Answer (score 0):

Setup PGP encryption within the application, it is perfectly secure and the information can be signed so that the receivers can check the authenticity of the sender.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy